# No windows whatsoever after compiz reset

Tags: unity, compiz

Currently using 12.04.
This time I was trying to use the application switcher, and it asked me to resolve a few conflicts most of which were not easy to comprehend.

So after some yes and no dialogue boxes leading me nowhere, I thought a reset should set things fine.

However, after preferences->reset to default, I can't see any window!! NONE whatsoever except the log out one when I press ctrl+alt+del

All I can see is the wallpaper and the mouse pointer. I cant even see the terminal or anything when I press alt+f2.

I am posting this when I switch to ubuntu 2d (I cant make out the difference between the two, but this just works for now almost the same way)

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem. I had to fix it by repairing ubuntu using the install disk. Compiz has been messing up recently and I would highly recommend  not using it.

If you want to try resetting it using the terminal you can access it using: Ctrl + Alt + F1

Here are some commands to try:

> sudo unity --reset

Try both of these together:

> sudo gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
>
> sudo gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compizconfig-1

Or you could try this:

> rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*

After executing these commands restart computer:

> sudo reboot

Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-reset-unity-launcher-icons-or.html

Hope this helps,

Leinardo

Comment: didnt work... unity --reset gave me some warnings related to compiz and a segmentation fault in the end. Those two commands didnt solve it either on a restart.. Thanks anyways :) I guess a fresh install is on its way

Comment: I believe `rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*` worked to solve my issue, but I can't be sure that all the settings are back the way it was originally.